# ajust div position with screensize

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have 2 `<div>` elements, one with a header and a paragraph of text and the other with a google map.

HTML:

```
<div id="info">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <p>
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
    </p>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

I want the `<div>` elements to stand next to each other while the screen is big enough (approximately 600px and up) and for the map `<div>` to go below the text `<div>` when the screen get smaller then the desired resolution.

At the moment I have a pretty ugly solution via jQuery as shown below:

```
function resize(){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < 768){
        $('#info').css('width','100%');
        $('#info').css('float','');
    }
    else{
        var width = $('#naviTable').width() - 350; 
        $('#info').css('width',width);
        $('#info').css('float','left');
    }
}
```

The `#navi-table` is an orientation element since its the full width of the display area of the page.

since the map `<div>` is always the same width is there a smarter way then mine to get the desired effect. @media isn't what I'm looking for, since its only supported by recent browsers.

EDIT:

I've managed to fix the problem to some extent by using the `display:flex` attribute in CSS, but that showed new problems.

The new code is:
HTML:

```
<div id="info-box">
<div id="info">
<h1>TITLE</h1>
<p>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
</p>
</div>
<table id="mapTable"><tr><td>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<h2 id="mapLink">TEXT TEXT...</h2>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

and in css ive added:

```
#info-box{display:flex;}
#info{width:100%;}
#mapTable{width:300px;}
```

There's no JS this time around.

Problem is that IE doesn't understand the flex value in the display property... anyone know how ti fix this?

This fiddle shows how its doe when the fixed element and the relative element are switched(fixed element is left, and relative on the right): http://jsfiddle.net/hJzJf/

but i need the other way around.

Comment: why don't you use CSS @media queries instead?

Comment: Just a tip, you can chain jquery commands on the same element. Like `$('#info').css('width','100%').css('float','');`

Comment: There are a few [Media Query pollyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#media-queries-spec) out there that may help if that is a route you would be interested in.

Comment: The chance of anything other than a "recent browser" viewing your page at less than 768 with is very little. Don't waste your time and energy catering to IE8 users who have their browsers at half the screen size (does anyone know an IE8 user that uses their browser that way?) Use a media query and set a fixed width on the body for IE8 users so they see a horizontal scroll bar below whatever width is acceptable to you.

Comment: And yes, that was a vote for using CSS media queries, but don't use a media query polyfill, IE8 JS/rendering engines will barely be able to handle it making the point of using a polyfill moot.

Comment: Another approach would be to enable/disable stylesheets based on screen width: [Quirks mode: stylsheets](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html) (search for `disabled`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#left {
    background: #f00;
    height: 200px;
}
#right {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #0f0;
    height: 200px;
}

@media all and (min-width:600px){
    #left {
        float: left;
        width: 180px;
    }
    #right {
        margin-left: 180px;
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hJzJf/117/

Comment: this behavior is fine, but the fixed block should be on the right. I've tried exchanging the float attribute and changing the value to right but no luck, the div skips to the next line.

Comment: You want the "nav" at the right? Easy. Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/hJzJf/118/

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and (min-width:600px){
    div{
        display:inline;
        margin-left:/*some amount*/
    }       
}

@media all and (max-width:599px){
    div{
        display:block;
    }       
}
```

Comment: this did not help I'm afraid.